# total number of ways of to target $8$ objects

Tags: combinatorics

$8$ clay target are arranged as shown in figure below. In how many ways can they be shot(one at a time). If no target can be shot until the target(s) below it have been shot.

[image]

What i try

We have total $8$ target , $3$ in first column and $2$ in second column and $3$ in third column

Which is $\displaystyle \binom{8}{3}$ ways

But answer is $560$

How do i solve it Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From total $8$ shooting time, You need to choose at what time You shoot the target in first column, $\binom{8}{3}$. Then from the remaining $5$ shooting time You choose at what time You shoot the target in the second column, $\binom{5}{2}$.

$\binom{8}{3}\times\binom{5}{2}=560$

The key point here is that You do not choose which target You shoot. You choose which column and then You shoot the bottom target in that column.

Answer (score 3):

Of all the 8! orderings of the targets some are legal (shoot targets in each column from the bottom up) and a lot will be illegal (shoot targets in at least one column in a different order than bottom up). For each legal ordering you can reorder within each column in 3!, 2! and 3! ways to obtain any of the 8! orderings (legal or illegal). Thus the number of legal orderings are 8!/(3!2!3!). This gives the same number as in Rezha’s answer.